# Pandas - get columns where all values are unique (distinct)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with many column and I am trying to get the columns where all values are unique (distinct).

I was able to to this for columns without missing values:

```
df.columns[df.nunique(dropna=False) == len(df)]
```

But I can't find a simple solution for columns with NaNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `nunique` and `count`

```
df.columns[df.nunique() == df.count()]
```

##### How this works?

- `nunique` counts the `unique` values (excluding NaN's)
- `count` as the name suggests counts all the values (excluding NaN's)

Comment: `df.count` still counts `np.nan` though

Comment: Nope. it will not count NaN values

Comment: If it is a `np.array` it counts. Try this out `df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['Europa', np.nan]), columns=['GroupId'])` Then `df.count()` gives 2.

Comment: @NuriTaş You are misunderstanding objects with NaN...When you create an array with mixed  type like in your proposed example `np.array(['Europa', np.nan])`..numpy will automatically convert `np.nan` to the string representation which is `'nan'` and therefore when you do count you will get 2 which is expected.

Answer (score 2):

This will print all columns that contains unique values excluding NaN

```
[col for col in df.columns if df[col].dropna().is_unique ]
```

Here is another one liner solution without using loop

```
df.columns[df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().is_unique, axis=0)]
```

To get it in an array form you can use

```
df.columns[df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().is_unique, axis=0)].array
```

Comment: thanks, I was looking for something without a loop but I guess it is good enough

Comment: @AndreF can you try my updated answer please, its without using loop

Comment: thanks for your answer. Shubham Sharma's answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column names where all values are unique as follows

```
all_unique = [item for item in df.columns if len(df) == len(df[item].unique())]
```

Then you can simply call them as usual to get the column with only unique values

```
df[all_unique]
```